# react-pdf, problema al renderizar pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, next.js

estoy teniendo un problema para renderizar pdfs provenientes de AWS a modo de stream, esos streams los transformo a url la cual paso al componente de react-pdf para abrirlo pero no logro desifrar porque no me funciona la url.

Este es mi funcion para obtener el stream del archivo:

```
`openDocument: async (applicantId, documentId) => {
    const { headerAxios } = userStore.getState();
    const url = `loan/documents/${applicantId}/download/${documentId}`;
    const config = {
      responseType: "blob",
      headers: headerAxios.headers,
    };
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url, config);

      const blobData = response.data;
      const dataUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blobData);

      set({
        loading: false,
        hasError: false,
        error: null,
      });
      console.log(typeof dataUrl);
      return dataUrl;
    } catch (error) {
      set({ loading: false, hasError: true, error: error?.response?.data });
      return error;
    }
  }`
```

Esta funcion me retorna este url (por ejemplo) : blob:http://localhost:3000/f4132e29-846a-4e71-bc5f-80af080e3ebe , entonces la paso a mi componente de esta manera :

```
` <Document
                    file={{ url: docs }}
                    onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
                    onLoadError={(error) => console.log("Inside Error", error)}
                    className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center py-4"
                  >
                    {!loading && renderedPages.map((page) => page)}
                  </Document>`
```

estos son los imports :

```
`import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from "react-pdf";
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;`
```

, y esto me retorna : GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found) , ya intente pasarlo sin el objeto de url y pasarlo directo pero no funciona tampoco, y en consola me arroja :

```
`{
    "message": "Missing PDF \"http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]\".",
    "name": "MissingPDFException"
}`
```

, no estoy seguro del porque me arroja de esta manera si en la documentacion de reat-pdf dice que se pase de esa manera y no encuentro mucha informacion al respecto,

la version de react pdf es la siguiente :  "react-pdf": "^6.0.0",  si alguien me pudiera orientar en este problema se lo agradeceria mucho , buen dia!

De nuevo : ya intentes pasarlo el objeto de url y con , pero no funciona al parecer.